# How to group the first value (string) and add the values of the same dates?

Tags: javascript, grouping

JAVASCRIPT - JQUERY
sum the values
How to group the first value (the date) and add the values of the same dates?

ARRAY :

```
0: (5) ["11-2019", 0, 20, 0, 0]
1: (5) ["11-2019", 41, 0, 0, 0]
2: (5) ["11-2019", 0, 0, 29, 0]
3: (5) ["11-2019", 0, 0, 0, 60]
4: (5) ["09-2019", 0, 1, 0, 0]
5: (5) ["09-2019", 0, 0, 1, 0]
6: (5) ["09-2019", 0, 0, 0, 1]
7: (5) ["05-2019", 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

OUT :

```
0: (5) ["11-2019", 41, 20, 29, 60]
1: (5) ["09-2019", 0, 1, 1, 1]
2: (5) ["05-2019", 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

```
result = DataAll.reduce(function(r, a) {
     a.forEach(function(b, i) {

         r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + b;
         console.log(r[i]);
     });
     return r;
 }, []);
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far and how it failed.

Comment: result = DataAll.reduce(function(r, a) {
                a.forEach(function(b, i) {

                    r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + b;
                    console.log(r[i]);
                });
                return r;
            }, []);

Comment: It is necessary to group by date and only add the values of the same dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find the array in the result set and update all values.

```js
var data = [["11-2019", 0, 20, 0, 0], ["11-2019", 41, 0, 0, 0], ["11-2019", 0, 0, 29, 0], ["11-2019", 0, 0, 0, 60], ["09-2019", 0, 1, 0, 0], ["09-2019", 0, 0, 1, 0], ["09-2019", 0, 0, 0, 1], ["05-2019", 2, 0, 0, 0]],
    result = data.reduce((r, a) => {
        var temp = r.find(([date]) => date === a[0])
        if (temp) {
            for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) temp[i] += a[i];
        } else {
            r.push([...a]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes, right - I started too soon on my own answer when the word "sum" wasn't in the post, or, maybe I didn't see it! Definitely, yours should be the correct answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

I added a `filter` to your script to remove the 0-values from the results. If you really want the 0 values use

```
acc[curr[0]]=(acc[curr[0]]||[]).concat(curr.slice(1));
```

instead.

```js
var inp=[["11-2019", 0, 20, 0, 0],
 ["11-2019", 41, 0, 0, 0],
 ["11-2019", 0, 0, 29, 0],
 ["11-2019", 0, 0, 0, 60],
 ["09-2019", 0, 1, 0, 0],
 ["09-2019", 0, 0, 1, 0],
 ["09-2019", 0, 0, 0, 1],
 ["05-2019", 2, 0, 0, 0]];
 var out=inp.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
   acc[curr[0]]=(acc[curr[0]]||[]).concat(curr.slice(1).filter(v=>v>0));
   return acc
 }, {});
  console.log(out);
  
  // and to get it into your format:
  var outarr=Object.keys(out).map(k=>[k].concat(out[k]))
  console.log(outarr)
```

Right, if you want the *sum* then my version would be the following. Thanks to Nina for supplying a correct answer first. ;-)

```js
var inp=[["11-2019", 0, 20, 0, 0],
 ["11-2019", 41, 0, 0, 0],
 ["11-2019", 0, 0, 29, 0],
 ["11-2019", 0, 0, 0, 60],
 ["09-2019", 0, 1, 0, 0],
 ["09-2019", 0, 0, 1, 0],
 ["09-2019", 0, 0, 0, 1],
 ["05-2019", 2, 0, 0, 0]];
 
 let out=inp.reduce((acc,cur)=>{
   if(acc[cur[0]]) acc[cur[0]].forEach((v,i,a)=>a[i]+=cur[i+1]);
   else acc[cur[0]]=cur.slice(1)
   return acc
 }, {} );
 outarr=Object.keys(out).map(k=>[k].concat(out[k]))
 
 console.log(outarr)
```